# Read file on linux

Tags: linux

Assume that there are 1k, 100k images in `./image0` and `./image1` respectively. Now I randomly read one image in these two directories respectively. What is the main source of the different elapsed time?

envs: ubuntu 14.04, ext4

Comment: That might depend on _how_ you implement that code for selecting and reading that image.

Comment: I am not quitely understand what you say. I read the image via `cv2.imread`.

Comment: I can only _assume_ that this refers to OpenCV and not the credit card verification scheme? If so, then did you measure really only the time to open and read the image or also for selecting it? That certainly would make a difference, that is why I asked for how that is coded. Maybe you could provide a minimal viable demonstration that shows the effect?

Comment: And another question: 100k is above the default limit of files that can be created inside a single folder on most file system types. Could you please also tell us a few details about what file system that is, how it is integrated with the local file system tree? Please add those details to the question itself, not in comments here. Thanks.

Comment: I think that the time to open image is same for the the two images are same. So I actually mean the time for selecting it. 100k is just a assumption and I really don't know that 100k is the default limit of files that can be inside a single folder.

Comment: The problem I met is that the time consuming is very different everytime I randomly read same number images from some image directories. And the reason I could think is that some directories contain large number of images and some contains a small number, which causes the time selecting image is different.

Comment: The default limit of the number of nodes you can create inside a file systems folder is not 100k! It is lower. Typically 32k, but that is a configuration question, you can define that when creating the file system. That default obviously also depends on the type of file system you are using.

Comment: Ah, ok, I understood from your questions that you could clearly pin down the difference to the number of nodes inside the folder. Now it turns out that is not the case, you only experience differences. So once more the question: what kind of share is that? Remember that mechanical disks experience much different speeds to access different files due to physical reasons. It takes different time to move the heads to different locations on the rotating disk _and_ different angle speeds are experienced which lead to different latencies.

Comment: In fact, I have check out the time consumed when the number of nodes inside the folder is different and I found it always changed. So I could not get conclusion from it. I know approximately how system read data from the mechanical disks. As I know, when we read file on linux, the fist thing to do is selecting the `inode` of the specific file and does the time consumed in this process differs for the different number of images inside the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125829/discussion-between-luohao-and-arkascha).